# Trying to fix/replace a ceiling light -- seen this type of mounting bracket anywhere?

Tags: light-fixture

A ceiling light was held in place by this plastic bracket and finally broke away.

[image]

Been searching all over trying to find a generic replacement bracket but everything seems to attach upwards. This fixture uses side screws to attach. I realize that part of the issue is that whoever installed the light used drywall screws which probably didnt help so I wont use those again. But any ideas where I could find a replacement for this bracket? I guess if nothing else I could try to drill holes and attach upwards using some of the generic brackets I have found at various home improvement stores.

[image]

Comment: What diameter is/was that piece which broke? Would a [4" "pancake" fan box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-6-cu-in-New-Construction-or-Remodel-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Pan-0103600/204845541?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CAll-Products%7CAll%7CAll%7CPLA%7c71700000014585962%7c58700001236285396%7c92700010802552412&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyLDpBRCxARIsAEENsrIFUxQa7Bc5eKC0Rqf363INUsgUl28B9HsHV0IdDDVpa7TUdxnBe4MaAmRoEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) work?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I thought about using the pancake fan box but would have to drill holes on the side for it to work with this fixture. Was trying to find something that would work without drilling, Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

That fixture was not made to use those screws; somebody rigged that by drilling pilot holes into a *plastic pancake ceiling box*, then used drywall screws.

They did this because the part of the fixture that was designed to attach to a ceiling box was missing. The original screws were machine thread screws and were supposed to "side screw" into the missing mating piece.

You might have some legit mounting options **if** there is an electrical box in the ceiling, behind that busted plastic box...

Comment: Thanks I didnt realize that blue bracket was just that.... if I remove the plastic ceiling box there is an electrical box in the ceiling. And I have been able to find several generic "brackets" I could use which would normally work great for most fixtures if the screws went upwards rather than on the sides of the light fixture.